# Alternative approach to force sequential javascript execution

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to execute multiple functions in JavaScript and force them to run sequentially. The most straight forward way to achieve this is to use callback functions (which has been the most commonly found suggestion on this forum and elsewhere). The problem with callback functions is that the resulting code can easily become hard to read as the result may be a lot of nested callback functions.
Am wondering if the following code will execute sequentially as well:

```
function doSomeThingOne(){
 //do something intense here that takes quite some processor time
 void(0); //dummy statement for illustration purposes only
 return true;
}

function doSomeThingTwo(){
 //do something intense here that takes quite some processor time
 void(0); //dummy statement for illustration purposes only
 return true;
}

function testSequentialExecution(){
 //a temporary variable just to capture the 
 var bolTemp=false;

 //execute the first function
 bolTemp=doSomeThingOne();

 //after this is done, execute the second function
 bolTemp=doSomeThingTwo();
}

//kick off the (hopefully) sequential execution
testSequentialExecution();
```

Am looking for a plain JavaScript solution.
If my functions doSomeThingOne() and doSomeThingTwo() do not execute code that runs a-synchronically (like a typical AJAX request) will this coding-style force the functions to execute synchronically?

Comment: Those two functions will still run one after the other. JS can do threading (via webworkers, but not very well supported).
Your best bet is to do the callback async method.

Comment: If you don't have *async*-code then everything will run sequentially. No need for callbacks whatsoever.

Comment: Can you even imagine a programming language which runs synchronous piece of code not in order?? It would be totally useless.

Comment: @freakish I kind of want one now so you can try and programme everything under race conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. That works just the same way JavaScript doesn't shuffle the content of any other function - expressions in a function will always be executed in order. Specifically, all expressions inside of a code block (something between `{}`) will always be executed in order. A function body is such a code block.

The expression might have async side effects (like calling `setTimeout()` or making AJAX calls) but the expression itself is evaluated in order. The browser can just determine to keep references to part of the expression and execute those parts later.

Your question seems like you spent too much time in the async world ;-)

The main problem is usually that you do something async. And then, the function ends and eventually, the callback will be called. There is no good way to serialize this. Maybe [JavaScript promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) will help.

Comment: Thank you Aaron! I am actually refacturing an application which I did not create myself and was wondering why it was not set-up in the way I suggested in my question. With your information I can now continue to refacture it and be sure that the refacturing process will not break the application.

Comment: I am left with one question: suppose my functions doSomeThingOne() and doSomeThingTwo() would not return a value - would the execution of the functions still be sequential?

Comment: JavaScript functions always return a value. See [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#General): "A function without a return statement will return a default value. In the case of a constructor called with the new keyword, the default value is the value of its this parameter. For all other functions, the default return value is  undefined."

Comment: Plus a function call is always also an expression, even if you don't assign the return value to a variable or use it in any other way.